# System.BadImageFormatException with Sqlite

Tags: wpf, sqlite

I am trying to use SQLite with my WPF application. I can get the reads and writes to work ok. The only problem I have is that my xaml is not displaying and I get the following error:

System.BadImageFormatException
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.80.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

My questions:
-How do I know what version of SQLite that I am using? 32bit or 64bit?
-I tried changing the Platform target to x86 and x64 but neither help. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had same problem when used 64-bit precompiled binaries. Solution is use 32-bit ones instead (manually download them from SQLite site if needed).

Answer (score 0):

A System.BadImageFormatException error often occurs when a 64-bit assembly is opened by a 32-bit application or Conversely. In this case, Visual Studio is a 32-bit application and the Design view is attempting to load a 64-bit assembly. Visual Studio assemblies are located in the project references tree.
Right click on Your Project and select properties item. In Build Tab, change platform target to Any CPU.